Editing a single event in an event series through Apex
I'm currently working on a use-case which requires me to sync both outlook and google calendars to Salesforce (which is why we cannot use EAC, as EAC only allows one calendar per org)
To this end, I want to create event series. My only problem is that when creating an event series, I seem to be unable to modify any of the specific event instances.
I have tried using IsRecurrence2Exception with flows, apex, anonymous apex, and this field is read-only.
I have tried modifying the event directly by using the startdatetime, but this gives an error :

To edit the start date of your series, delete this series and recreate it with a new start date

Has anyone succesfully implemented a similar use-case or succeeded in modifying a single instance in an event series?

For anybody else in the same issue, I ended up moving from the LEX event recurrence, to the classic event recurrence.
This meant I was not able to use the RRULE pattern, but at least I'm able to modify my events. I leveraged the Create a recurring Event or Task with Data Loader
I am now able to update the recurrence patterns, and delete specific instances of events. It works for my use case!
